# Trying to understand Hibernate sessions

Tags: java, hibernate

If I save an entity using a Hibernate session, and then probe to get this entity from the current session on the very next line (i.e. without the changes have been written to DB yet) will the session return an object? I assume it should, because it is also aware of what changes have been made to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the view of entities that have been saved and those being loaded/queries should be consistent. Sometimes querying causes all the outstanding changes to the database to be flushed before the query is performed, in order to produce this consistency (assuming the session is set to the default auto-flush mode).

Further, in this case, the session should return the exact same object that you saved, not a copy that refers to the same row in the database.

Comment: but it returns null on a JUnit test which extends from AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests and is marked as transactional

Comment: how are you "probing" for the entity? using a query? did the session auto-flush before it? does putting a session.flush() call before the query help?

Comment: I simply save, flush, and then try to grab it from the session on the next line ... and it returns null, although I see the INSERT SQL being sent to the DB. Could it be that the test is marked as @Transactional?

Answer (score 0):

It should,  but you have to be careful while implementing equality and hashcode. Session is just a big hashmap with entities keyed by object ID.  So if you try to retrieve object by ID,  you shall  get  the same object.